# Swift - translate cURL into Swift request

Tags: swift, httprequest

I'm trying to use an external API to download data. I need to translate cURL to Swift.

This is cURL

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}"
```

I have the following code

```
           guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.lucidtech.ai/v0/receipts"),


      let payload = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myClienID&client_secret=myClientSecret".data(using: .utf8)

        else
        {
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue(" application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = payload

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
            guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(str)
            }
        }.resume()
```

It doesn't work.

I don't know how to include client_id and client_secret.

How can I do this?

Comment: Change `client_id=myClienID` to `client_id=\(myClienID)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that you can use:

```swift
let headers = [
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
]

let postData = NSMutableData(data: "grant_type=client_credentials".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        postData.append("&client_id={client_id}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        postData.append("&client_secret={client_secret}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token")! as URL,
                                                cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                            timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData as Data

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
          if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
          } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
            //parse your model here from `data` 
          }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: After sending this request I should get as a reply containing 
`{
    "type": "amadeusOAuth2Token",
    "username": "foo@bar.com",
    "application_name": "BetaTest_foobar",
    "client_id": "3sY9VNvXIjyJYd5mmOtOzJLuL1BzJBBp",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "CpjU0sEenniHCgPDrndzOSWFk5mN",
    "expires_in": 1799,
   ...
}`

Comment: But I get this: 
` { URL: https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Accept =     (
        "*/*"
    );
    "Accept-Encoding" =     (
        "gzip, deflate, br"
    );
    "Accept-Language" =     (
        "en-us"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =     (
        "origin, x-requested-with, accept, Content-Type"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" =     (
        "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "*"
    );
  ...
} })

There wasn't field "access_token"

Comment: in this code, it's print `response`. You can use 'data' and decode it as you want

Comment: I add a comment in my code where you should use `data` not `response`